# summing decimal number in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please anybody with mysql query to sum up values of a column in a database. The values are numbers with a decimal point e.g., 14,166,636.17. The code is below

```
SELECT `amt_paid` am 
FROM csda 
WHERE amt_paid > 0
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(`amt_paid`) as total FROM csda WHERE amt_paid > 0

Answer (score 0):

Given the `amt_paid` column string-typed, you can:

- remove all commas from the strings using `REPLACE` function
- transform strings into numeric values using `0+ <string_value>`
- sum up all floats bigger than 0 using the `SUM` aggregation function

```
SELECT SUM(float_num) AS AM
FROM (SELECT 0+ REPLACE(amt_paid, ',', '') AS float_num
      FROM csda) cte
WHERE float_num > 0
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fhELt1qiCqqiYFLbt2A9aK/0).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but when I run the query, it brought this:   1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)
SQL query: Documentation

WITH cte AS(SELECT 0+ REPLACE(amt_paid, ',', '') AS float_num FROM csda) SELECT SUM(float_num) AS AM FROM cte WHERE float_num > 0

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte AS(SELECT 0+ REPLACE(amt_paid, ',', '') AS float_num FROM csda)
SELECT SUM(' at line 1

Comment: My guess is that you're using MySQL 5.X, hence it doesn't recognize ctes. Try with the subquery construct, as updated in the answer @SafebetHub